Adding force to a game object (slide effect after jump) - jitter problems caused by deltatime multiplication
//inside update method which is called 60/120 times per second
long currentFrameTime = System.nanoTime();
float deltaTime = (currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime) / 1_000_000_000.0f;
lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

float nextForceSlide = forceSlide - forceSlideDecreaseRate * deltaTime;
if (nextForceSlide < 0) {
   forceSlide = 0;
} else forceSlide = nextForceSlide;

updatePosition(this, game.joyStick.angle, forceSlide * deltaTime);


//method
public void updatePosition(Entity entity, double angle, float length) {
   entity.position.x = entity.position.x + length * (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
   entity.position.y = entity.position.y + length * (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
}


This is how i try to add a little force to the player into the direction where it is currently looking at. Since i want to support 30 60 120 fps the result of the applied force should be same for each. But right now it feels jittery not smooth when the player is sliding. Why?
I try to add a little force to my player, so it slides after a jump movement. Currently it feels very jittery. I expected it to be smooth.

@easleyfixed when i remove the deltatime multiplication in game.physicsEngine.updatePosition(this, game.joyStick.angle, forceSlide * deltaTime); it gets smooth as i would have expected it, but then the added slide force would be different for different frame rates(30, 60, 120 etc.).
